# schunk_svh_driver - effort

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why when I call

```
rostopic echo /svh_controller/channel_feedback
```

I get:

```
name: ['Thumb_Flexion', 'Thumb_Opposition', 'Index_Finger_Distal', 'Index_Finger_Proximal', 'Middle_Finger_Distal', 'Middle_Finger_Proximal', 'Ring_Finger', 'Pinky', 'Finger_Spread']

position: [0.05220882358116796, 0.0899018990503464, 0.15354111584201746, 0.10189999742578948, 0.15404356030194322, 0.1026399974070955, 0.11117555604869267, 0.11235155605390901, 0.2843675514932329]

velocity: []

effort: []
```

and so I have value of current positions but I haven't value of velocity and effort?
Then is the effort the contact force???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208097/schunk_svh_driver---effort/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

only name and position is used:

channel_targets (sensor_msgs/JointState)

```
Target position the channels (fingers) shall move to. Note that it is less performant to give targets for individual channels or a subset of the available DoF than providing it for all at once. If 8 channels are given instead of 9 the driver will send 8 packets instead of 1 which might influence serial device performance. Only the names and positions will be evaluated from the JointState message.
```

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-28**:
How I can read the value of current or effort?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-28**:
with rosparam

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-28**:
"effort" isn't in the list of setted parameters.

**Comment by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) on 2015-06-09**:
The Rosparams with "currents" are the values you set for the current controller ( the low level driver of the hand). PLEASE be very carefull with these! Also they will at the moment only be read during startup of the node and are not changable at runtime.